# Reactive Extensions in .Net (C#) - Subject<T> instance only processing one subscription

Tags: c#, observable, reactive-programming, system.reactive, observers

so I'm hoping my title is accurate enough, but I'm very much in a 'can't see the wood for the trees' state right now.

I've been investigating reactive extensions for C# for a little while and up until now it has behaved intuitively and wonderfully, then I encountered an issue:

I create a Subject
I create a single value Observable.Create and call subscribe for the Subject
The value then happily pops into my `OnNext()` lambda, hooray!

However, if I create a subsequent Observable.Return and subscribe... Nothing happens, and the Subject contains `HasObservers: false`

I have thrown together a minimal console snippet that demonstrates the problem

```cs
    using System.Reactive.Linq;
    using System.Reactive.Subjects;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Subject<string> messenger = new Subject<string>();
        messenger.Where(o => o.Length > 0).Subscribe(file => { Console.WriteLine("got file request: " + file); });

        var pathObservable = Observable.Return<string>("File 1");
        pathObservable.Subscribe(messenger);

        var pathObservable2 = Observable.Return<string>("File 2");
        pathObservable2.Subscribe(messenger);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Result:

[image: Subject subscription example]

Note: Before anyone asks why I'm doing something silly like using two observables where one sequence would do, this is merely an example; in reality the two separate observable creation calls are independent and instigated by external requests for a file, in which case the trouble is that the first request succeeds, the second does not.

I have tried using Observable.Create() instead, and calling OnNext with the single value, with the same result; interestingly having a breakpoint in the lambda in this case shows that the OnNext is being called for the second observable, it's just not popping out into the Subject

Any ideas on what I've missed or what I'm misunderstanding very welcome,
thanks in advance

Comment: Update: So it looks like the completion of the first observable terminates the subject... So how would one keep a subject around for multiple re-uses? I don't want my post-person to vanish because they delivered one letter. nor do I want them to wait around for all possible letters before delivering any!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to only subscribe to `OnNext` messages, as Paulo's suggests. You can also remove or suppress `OnCompleted` messages from the observable.

However, the best way to do this is to probably replace the `messenger` Subject. I don't know your larger use case, but a good goal is to minimize Subject use. They're great for learning, and terrible for applications.

In this case, you can replace the whole code with a one-liner:

```
Observable.Merge(
        Observable.Return<string>("File 1"),
        Observable.Return<string>("File 2")
    )
    .Where(o => o.Length > 0)
    .Subscribe(file => Console.WriteLine("got file request: " + file));
```

If you wanted to simulate dynamically adding observables, you would probably want to do that with a `Subject<IObservable<string>>`:

```
Subject<IObservable<string>> consoleWriter = new Subject<IObservable<string>>();
consoleWriter
    .Merge()
    .Where(o => o.Length > 0)
    .Subscribe(file => Console.WriteLine("got file request: " + file));

var pathObservable = Observable.Return<string>("File 1");
consoleWriter.OnNext(pathObservable);

var pathObservable2 = Observable.Return<string>("File 2");
consoleWriter.OnNext(pathObservable2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I worked this out shortly afterwards through experimentation and head-scratching.

The first example would not work for me, as I put in the note, the two observables would actually happen at different times, so can;t really be explicitly merged.

I had essentially misunderstood what the 'onComplete' would do, having assumed it would merely clean up the observable and notify any subscribers to the OnCompleted. But as it does more, I have rearranged it all.

Answer (score 1):

By having `messenger` subscribe to another observable, you'll have it subscribe to `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleted`.

If you add this after creating the `Subject<string>`, you'll se it being completed:

```
messenger.Subscribe(_ => {}, e => Console.WriteLine(e), () => Console.WriteLine("Completed"));
```

If, instead, you add just an on-next action, the subject won't be completed:

```
Subject<string> messenger = new Subject<string>();
messenger.Where(o => o.Length > 0).Subscribe(file => { Console.WriteLine("got file request: " + file); });

var pathObservable = Observable.Return<string>("File 1");
pathObservable.Subscribe(v => messenger.OnNext(v));

var pathObservable2 = Observable.Return<string>("File 2");
pathObservable2.Subscribe(v => messenger.OnNext(v));

messenger.OnNext("File 3");

Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
got file request: File 1
got file request: File 2
got file request: File 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I worked out what the issue was, having an oncomplete call was cleaning up more than I thought/hoped it was.

Appreciate the response